# How to convert/save a dynamical image() into a png and used it as background in a dynamic plot, all insight a shiny app

Tags: r, image, png, converters, shinyapps

From an R code non-dynamical that works correctly even if the code is not perfect, I was trying to replicate it in shiny app but doing it dynamically. I manage to make the plot dynamic and work fine, but I can't do it with the background that even need to be dynamic. I manage to do an image dynamically but I can't manage to transform this dynamic image into an image.png to do make some adjustments and late use as the background of the plot. I read tons of articles and I didn't manage to find the solution. I try saving the dynamic image (image())as .png in the www folder to after reopening it, I try doing a temporary .png file to avoid saving in www but I can't see how to use and manipulate it outside the Output file. I try other things that I can't remember at the moment sorry. Is there somebody that can help with this problem? Probably the solution is not complex but I don't manage to find the right way at the moment.

I am trying to pass from this image  [image] that is a dynamic image(x(),y(),z(),col = terrain.colors(18), alpha=0.5, rev=TRUE) to the same one image but in .PNG extention, after that manipulate it to arrive at this image also in .PNG extension [image] to use it as background in a dynamic plot (ggplot). Again, ll insight a Shyni app. I hope it is clear the information, the problem and the final result. Thank you in advance

```
f <-function(x,y)  2*x*(y**2)+2*(x**2)*y+x*y


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  

  
F8fR = reactive({
req(FTselect())
FTselect() %>% mutate(Pos = as.factor(Pos)) %>%
filter(ppg > 3.5 | ppm > 0.5)
})        
          
x = reactive({
req(F8fR())
seq(min(F8fR()$ppm, na.rm=T),max(F8fR()$ppm,    na.rm=T),len=length(F8fR()$ppm))
})
          
y = reactive({
req(F8fR())
seq(min(F8fR()$ppg, na.rm=T),max(F8fR()$ppg, na.rm=T),len=length(F8fR()$ppg))
})
          
z = reactive({
req(x(),y())
outer(x(),y(),f)
})        
## until here seems to work well  
  
## Problem start here!!!!!!!!!work well in R code but not under Shiny
   
png("Optimalr.png")
image(x(),y(),z(),col = terrain.colors(18), alpha=0.5, rev=TRUE)
dev.off()
  
tiger <- image_read("Optimalr.png") #, width = 480, height = 480

tigerc <- image_crop(tiger,      "480x480+59+59",gravity="NorthWest",repage=TRUE)
tigercc <- image_crop(tigerc, "421x421+30+73",gravity="SouthEast",repage=TRUE)
image_write(tigercc, path = "Optimalrc.png", format = "png")
 

  
#Step 1:Import the image
img <- png::readPNG("Optimalrc.png")

#until here there is the problem



## From here work
       
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
          
#Step 2: Create the plot with R code
ggplot(F8fR(), aes( x=ppm, y=ppg)) +
background_image(tigercc) + 
geom_jitter(data=F8fR(), aes( x=ppm, y=ppg, size=3, colour=Pos)) +
geom_text_repel(aes(label = Name), size=3, box.padding = 0.25, 
point.padding = 0.3, 
segment.color = 'grey50') +  
xlab("Points x Game x Million") +
theme (plot.title = element_text(  size = 20, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1),
axis.title.x = element_text(colour="Black", size=15),
axis.title.y = element_blank(),#element_text(colour = "Blue", size=15),
axis.text.x = element_text(size=12),
axis.text.y = element_blank(),#element_text(size=12),
legend.title = element_text(size=10),
legend.text = element_text(size=10),
legend.position = c(0.95, 0.15),
legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent", size=3,
linetype="solid"),
) +
labs(caption=paste("Data from Lamarque Brothers",Sys.Date(),sep=""))
},height = 578)
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```